# .htaccess file causes .php to be downloaded

Tags: php, asp.net, .htaccess, download

I made a .htaccess file. And I upload file in a index.php, index.php was downloaded instead of being run as a php file. I think the .htaccess file makes php downloadable.
The php file was on the same path with .htaccess file.
The problem is solved , but I wonder why that is downloaded.

My .htaccess file is this.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-asp .php
```

Comment: This is a Windows server? uh, ASP is not PHP, so that Addtype line is certainly not correct.. Normally it's like 
AddType xphp5 .php                but the "xphp5" part will vary depending on your setup.

Answer (score 1):

That directive tells Apache to process PHP files using ASP. Since it apparently can't process ASP (likely since ASP is not installed by default), it then moves to send headers to instruct the browser to download the file (which is the default for anything Apache doesn't know how to process).

It's not normal to have a directive like that